# How many solutions are there to this system of equation, 8 or 2?

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose I have the following system of equations:

$x = a$

$y = a$

$z = a$

And I find that $a = \pm 5$

How many solutions does this mean there are to the system of equations?

(For convinience lets say that I talk about all of the solutions like this: i.e. $(5,5,5)$ means $x=5, y=5, z=5$)

(1) Only two solutions? $(+5,+5,+5), (-5,-5,-5)$

(2) 8 solutions: $(+5, +5, +5), (+5, +5, -5), ...$

I am confused about this.  I'm thinking the answer should be (2), but was told by a professor the correct answer is (1)

Why is it (1) ?

Comment: This is similar to when I have students check solutions to a quadratic equation, say $x^2-3x+2 = 0$ (with solutions $x = 1$ and $x = 2$), by substituting different values for $x$ at the same time, i.e.: $(1)^2 -3(2) + 2 = 0$. In your case, having selected a particular value for $a$, the first three equations imply that $x = y = z$.

Comment: A solution set contains the values such that all the equations of the system are *simultaneously* true. The system implies $x=y=z=a$. So for example, the selection $(5,5,-5)$ posits that $5=-5$. This clearly doesn't work! The choice of + or – matters each time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's make it simple.  Suppose $x = a$ and $y = a$.  Then by transitivity, $x = y$.  Therefore, any solution of the system $x = a$ and $y = a$ **must** also satisfy the third equation; i.e., $x = y$, even if $a$ is allowed to take on multiple values.

Here's another example:  $$x = a^2, \quad y = a^2, \quad a^2 = 4.$$  Then there are two solutions for $a$, namely $a = -2$ or $a = 2$, but only one solution for $x$ and $y$:  $x = y = 4$.  The complete solution set is $$(x,y,a) \in \{(4,4,2), (4,4,-2)\}.$$

Answer (score 1):

It is two solutions. The $x, y, z$ depend on a particular choice of $a$ and there are two values for $a$.